# Can chemical potential be directly measured like this?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I have a system of a pure ideal gas $a$, which I call 'the reference', with a known $P^{ref}, V^{ref}, T^{ref}$ and $n^{ref}_a$. I know the chemical potential formula for an ideal gas, so can calculate how it changes as its variables change.

I place it next to an unknown system with unknown chemical potential $\mu_a$. This system must me "much bigger" than my reference so that it isn't disturbed by their interaction.

I make the separation a fixed membrane permeable only to $a$, and put both in contact with a bath of $T = T^{ref}$.

I wait for the systems to reach equilibrium, and measure $P^{ref}, V^{ref}, T^{ref}$ and $n^{ref}_a$, which let's me calculate how $\mu^{ref}_a$ changed.

Thermodynamics say that at equilibrium $\mu^{ref}_a$ must have become equal to the unknown $\mu_a$. So I just measured the difference between the unknown $\mu_a$ and the initial reference $\mu^{ref}_a$.

This device then let's me directly measure chemical potential (relative to a reference).

**Is this correct? Can chemical potential be directly measured like this?**

I believe this is completely analogous to how thermodynamic pressure is measured, (relative to a reference like atmospheric pressure), by connecting two systems through a movable wall and letting it reach equilibrium.

I was thinking maybe ph meters are an example of this. Osmotic pressure tubes too.

Comment: Only if the mixture and the pure component in the reference state behave as ideal gases.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In my example the reference system is a pure ideal gas that always remains pure and ideal. The unknown system can be anything and behave in any way, but its so big that nothing significant will happen to it.

Comment: If  you are describing an experimental procedure to measure the chemical potential of a gas, at higher pressures the gas is not going to be behaving as an ideal gas (both the pure gas and the gas mixture).  So, for the pure gas, you need to take into account non-ideality.